# Automate docker swarm config rotation

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'd like to deploy a service to docker swarm that uses a config.

I understand that to update configs they need to be rotated. This means some manual docker commands are run to:

1. Add a new version of the config file (different name from the original) to the swarm manager.
2. Update the existing services that may be consuming the old config, and give them the new config file instead of the old.

This is quite a bit of manual work to juggle and so I'm looking to automate it.

My idea is to have some service that will be independent deployed to the swarm to perform monitoring of services (and their labels) and use custom labels to work out which services are interested in which configs. This service will also monitor a physical directory containing the config files, and when it detects a config file change in the physical directory, it will compute a new name for the config in swarm- and using the service labels it can auto rotate the config for all those services that are "subscribed".

This means teams would no longer need to rotate configs by running commands on the swarm manually, or check in commits to docker compose files with new secret names - only an admin would need to update the physical config file in the monitored config directory and this service would take care of the rest in terms of updating subscribed services.

My question is, had this problem already been solved, is there something I can already use to achieve this? Please don't answer with "kubernetes" - I'm focusing on swarm only. Also I am aware of a docker swarm monitor service to notify me of new services and plan to use that.

Comment: This is where docker swarm stopped being convenient for me. Try Kubernetes if you still haven't, it has much more flexibility when it comes to managing config files/secrets. K8s allows changing contents of a config object without giving it a new name. After updating configuration, the only thing to do is to trigger a container restart.

Comment: I've scripted this as part of the deploy over here: https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-config-update

Comment: Thanks both. It looks like (without switching to k8s) there is a need for something that makes this more admin friendly. @BMitch thanks for the script I hadn't considered the need to query the latest config name for use at deployment time for the variables in compose file. I think I can make a service that will offer an API for this, as well as a UI for managing the configs, and some nice features like ability for services to opt in (via a label) whether they want to be auto restarted when configs they depend on are rotated. I'll report back here if I make progress.